# How can i disable opacity in div container with CSS?

Tags: html, css, web, opacity

i have two div-tags

```
<div class="1" style="opacity:0.5">
  <div class="2"></div>
</div>
```

Div1 do have a opacity so div2 also have a opacity.

What can i do to disable opacity in div2?

Div2 have to be in div1 so i cannot change the order of the divs.

Comment: Do you want to do something to prevent any sort of opacity in _div2_, so that if _div1_ is transparent, _div2_ shouldn't have any opacity (transparency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want opacity to lighten the background color of Div1, you may use following css.

`<div class="1" style="background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);">`

It will then not affect your Div2 content.

Note: One should use external css file to write css instead inline css. I've used the same just to better help you on your issue.

Comment: youre right. thanks a lot!